# Авторизация на jQuery+PHP+SQL

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql

Стоит задача сделать авторизацию на jQuery+PHP+SQL.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($("#loginText").val()!=""&&$("#passwordText").val()!=""){
         $.ajax({
        url:"login.php",
        method:"POST",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success:function(html){toVote(html);}      
     });
    }
   else{
       $("#error").html("Не введен логин или пароль");
   }
});

var toVote=function(html){
    if(html=="error"){
        $("#error").html("Логин или пароль введен неверно");
        $("#loginText").val("");
        $("#passwordText").val("");
    }
    else{
        window.location = '/project/voting.html';
        }
     };
   });
```

Вопрос состоит в следующем. Как сделать так, что бы на страницу voting.html нельзя было попасть незалогиненному пользователю, просто набрав адрес URL? Т.Е как определять залогиненность пользователя при вызове html страницы через AJAX?

Comment: Я вижу только одно решение: когда вызываешь страницу через AJAX, то отправлять еще один запрос на PHP страницу, где та будет отвечать: залогинен он или нет. А что бы напрямую не входило, надо через `.htaccess` делать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а что мешает сохранить статус "залогинен/незалогинен" в $_SESSION и там же проверять при обработке ajax-запроса ?